# Javascript / JQuery prevent scroll on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a mobile web app and have added the following code when a form is loaded:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
```

This stops the user from scrolling and works for all **div** elements.  However if a user "drags" on a text input box, the page will scroll.

Is it possible to stop this?

I'm happy to use javascript or jquery.

Comment: may be this will help
window.touchmove 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove

Comment: window.ontouchmove worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.ontouchmove` instead of `document.ontouchmove` works.